# How to make a filter to check a value inside an array as a range?

Tags: search, range, couchdb

I have a database that has this:

```
{"total_rows":11111,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"0","key":["0","10"],"value":"A"},
{"id":"11","key":["11","23"],"value":"B"},
{"id":"24","key":["24","25"],"value":"C"},
{"id":"26","key":["26","41"],"value":"D"}
...
```

How can a send a parameter like value=17 and get the correspondent document which is: `{"id":"11","key":["11","23"],"value":"B"}` (17 inside the range [11,23])?

In just JS i was trying:

```
function l(e){
  if(Number(e.key[0])>=Number(this) && Number(e.key[1])<=Number(this)){
     return e.value;
  } 
}
v.find(l,17);
```

But still does not work...
Thank you.

EDIT:
Correction:

```
function l(e){
  if(Number(e.key[0])<=Number(this) && Number(e.key[1])>=Number(this)){
     return e.value;
  } 
}
v.find(l,17);
```

How to implement this in the view?

Comment: `>=` and  `<=` seem to be reversed in your check

Comment: You were right. That solved the problem in Js but how to implement this in CouchDB view or reduce map?